# How do I use assertions in with Xerces C++ 3.x (CodeSynthesis XSD)?

Tags: xml, xsd, xerces-c, codesynthesis

I have just read through this tutorial on XSD 1.1 assertions:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/

I copied one of their examples and created this `xsd` file:

```
<?xml version="1.1"?>                                                               
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">                             
<xs:element name="dimension">                                                    
  <xs:complexType>                                                               
    <xs:attribute name="height" type="xs:int"/>                                  
    <xs:attribute name="width" type="xs:int"/>                                   
    <xs:assert test="@height = @width"/>                                         
  </xs:complexType>                                                              
</xs:element>                                                                    

</xs:schema>
```

I am trying to parse this to code-gen an hxx file using *[CodeSynthesis XSD XML Schema to C++ compiler](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/xsd.xhtml) 4.0.0* using the following command:

> /path/to/binary cxx-tree /path/to/file.xsd

but I get the following error:

> /path/to/file.xsd:7:41: error: invalid element 'assert' in complex
>   type definition

I get the same error when I change the xml version to `1.0`. As I understand it the xml version shouldn't matter in this case, but I might be wrong.

What would cause this error message, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can vote for XSD 1.1 in Xerces-C++ here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESC-2198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XSD is using assertions properly.  (You probably want `version="1.0"` in your XML declaration as this is the *XML* version, not the XSD version, but that's not the source of the error.)

Your XSD processor does not support XSD 1.1 if it is rejecting your XSD.

**Update**: Indeed, according to [CodeSynthesis's website](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/download.xhtml), CodeSynthesis XSD 4.0.0 is based upon Xerces-C++, which does not support XSD 1.1.  CodeSynthesis really should make this explicit on their product page.

Comment: So is there anything I can do to achieve something similar to an `assert` using xerces-c++ (using a different XSD processor is not an option)? An example, if possible, would be appreciated.

Comment: No, the standard answer to these sorts of questions prior to XSD 1.1 was that you would have to check such constraints outside of XSD.  You might consider custom code or Schematron.  There is no way to do it in XSD 1.0 alone.  (That's why assertions were introduced in XSD 1.1.)